# Java concurrency: synchronized method and synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

i have two methods to add and remove elements from a circular buffer

the first implementation :

```
synchronized void add(byte b) throws InterruptedException {

  if(availableObjects == size) wait();
  buffer[(tail+1)%size] = b ;
  tail++;
  availableObjects++;
  notifyAll();
}

synchronized byte remove() throws InterruptedException {

  if(head==tail) wait();
  Byte element = buffer[head%size];
  head ++ ;
  availableObjects--;
  notifyAll();
  return element;

}
```

and the second implementation :

```
private final Object addLock= new Object ();
private final Object removeLock=new Object ();

void add (byte b) throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized (addLock){
        while (availaibleObjects.get () == size) addLock.wait();
        buffer [tail]= b;
        tail = [tail + 1) % size;
        availaibleObjects.incrementAndGet();}

    synchronized (removeLock){ // why we added this block ? 
        removeLock.notifyAll();}
    }


 byte remove () throws InterruptedException{
    byte element;
    synchronized (removeLock){
        while (availaibleObjects.get () == 0) removeLock.wait() ;
         element = buffer[head] ;
         head=(head + 1) % size;
         availaibleObjects.decrementAndGet();}

        synchronized (addLock){ // why we added this block ? 
            addLock.notifyAll();}
            return element;}
```

my question is why in the second implementation of the methods we added a second synchronized block  ?

1. from the first implementation i get that two threads cannot add and remove at the same time  .
2. from the second implementation two threads can add and remove at the same time but i don't understand why we added the blocks :

```
synchronized (removeLock){ // why we added this block ? 
        removeLock.notifyAll();}


 synchronized (addLock){ // why we added this block ? 
            addLock.notifyAll();}
            return element;}
```

Comment: Code must be in a `synchonized` block in order to do a `notifyAll()` and `wait` calls.

Comment: I would guess that all mutating operations (ie add and remove) should share the same lock. I can't imagine it is safe to perform an add and a remove concurrently.

Comment: @K.Nicholas yes i get that but why we added the `notifyAll()` into a synchronized block  ? we could've done that in the first block

Comment: Synchronized block is specific to object. RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is why in the second implementation of the methods we added a second synchronized block ?

Whenever you call `wait()` or `notify()` on an object, you must be in a `synchronized` block for that particular object.  So if you want to call `addLock.notifyAll();` you must be inside a `synchronized (addLock)`.  The `synchronized` keyword provides locking and also memory synchronization.

**WARNING:** More importantly, you have a bug because you are writing to `buffer` while inside the `addLock` synchronized block but reading inside `removeLock`.  A writer could be inside `addLock`, add the item, and increment the `availableObjects` counter while a reader is already inside of `addLock`. This would mean that the reader might *not* see the updates to `buffer` and might read an element as `null`.  If you are mutating `buffer` and then reading from it later, both should be holding in a `synchronized` block on the same object – you might as well lock on `buffer`.  With this change you can then downgrade `availableObjects` to be a normal `integer`.

> `addLock.notifyAll();`

If you do this right, you should be able to call `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()` since each element added or removed from the buffer will release at most 1 waiting thread.

> `if(availableObjects == size) wait();`

It is important to point out that your 2nd implementation is correct to change these from `if` to `while` statements.  It needs to be tested in a `while` loop otherwise you will have race conditions and bugs with multiple publishers and subscribers – also spurious wakeups on some architectures.  See [my page on these race conditions](https://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/).